# Compare equality of the values between two blocks of memory

Tags: c

This is part of my implementation of `kmean` algorithm. I have two blocks of memory both in equal size such that `*cluster_center`is the current center of cluster and `*new_centroids` represents the new centroid after taking the mean of the cluster's points:

```
double *cluster_center = malloc((k * dim) * sizeof(double));
double *new_centroids = malloc((k * dim) * sizeof(double));
```

I have the following loop to copy the results from the `new_centroids` to the `cluster_center` with no issues:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    memcpy(&cluster_center[i * dim], &new_centroids[i * dim], dim * sizeof(double));
}
```

In fact, I want to know if C has a built-it function to compare the **values** of both blocks since I want to terminate my algorithm once the **values** of `*new_centroids` and `*cluster_center` are the same (i.e., didn't change). I really don't know how to do that.

Thank you

Comment: Research `memcmp()` for a binary compare.  May be insufficient for comparing `double`  `+0.0`, `-0.0` and `NaN` need special handling.

Comment: You mean like [`memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp)?

Comment: I mean comparing the **values** of both arrays if they are similar. I think `memcmp` compares only the length not the actual values similarities!!

Comment: Similarly, if the arrays map the same way, you can `memcpy` the entire array in one go without any loop. (There is no need to use `memmove` since the memory ranges cannot overlap.)

Comment: `memcmp` compares only the length? No, you tell `memcmp` what the size is, it compares every byte value.

Comment: So why not simply use a loop like `for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    if (cluster_center[i + dim*k] != new_centroids[i + dim*k]) return not_equal;
} return equal;`?

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `memcmp` (memory compare). Immediately after you execute a statement:

```
memcpy(destination, source, size);
```

then

```
memcmp(destination, source, size);
```

should return zero.